# How to get path of current active application window?

Tags: windows, delphi, lazarus

I want to get the path to the executable file of the current active Window.

I tried:

```
var
  WindowModuleFileName : array[0..100] of Char;  
  sourceWindow: Hwnd;      
begin
  sourceWindow := GetActiveWindow;
  GetWindowModuleFileName(sourceWindow, PChar(WindowModuleFileName), sizeof(WindowModuleFileName));    
  ShowMessage(WindowModuleFileName);    
end;
```

But it returned correct answer only when my application window was active.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `GetWindowModuleFileName` to locate files for other processes than your own, as stated on [GetModuleFileName MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves the fully-qualified path for the file that contains the specified module. The module must have been loaded by the current process.
>
> To locate the file for a module that was loaded by another process,
>   use the GetModuleFileNameEx function.

Therefore, you have to use `GetModuleFileNameEx` combined with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`/`GetForegroundWindow`. This will return you what you need:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.PsAPI, System.SysUtils;

function GetCurrentActiveProcessPath: String;
var
  pid     : DWORD;
  hProcess: THandle;
  path    : array[0..4095] of Char;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow, pid);

  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
    try
      if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, @path[0], Length(path)) = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;

      result := path;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Presumably `GetWindowModuleFileName()` is a custom wrapper since 1) it is not an API function, and 2) it is being passed an `HWND` as a parameter. `GetModuleFileName/Ex()` expects an `HMODULE` instead.  BTW, there are also [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217.aspx) and [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919.aspx) API functions available. They do not require `PROCESS_VM_READ` rights. In fact, they even work with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` rights.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not an API function, @Remy? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633517.aspx

Comment: @RobKennedy: I learned something new. I had never heard of that API function before. However, I don't see anything in its documentation that prohibits it from getting the filename of a window that belongs to another process. AFAIK that restriction only applies to `GetModuleFileName()`, whose documentation is what Marko quoted from. I'll have to test `GetWindowModuleFileName()`  and see what happens.

Comment: This works fine with most programs, but it always CRASHES with some SPECIFIC programs (e.g. KeePass, DOpus, ...). I could not find out why.

Answer (score 3):

`GetActiveWindow` gets the window handle to the active window that belongs to the calling thread only.

You need to use `GetForegroundWindow()` function instead of `GetActiveWindow()`.